# can't access video device from Docker Container

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, video-capture, v4l2

Here is my DockerFile:

```
FROM python:3.10.4
LABEL maintainer="Louis Jefferson Zhang <louis.ljz08@gmail.com>"

# Set environment variables
ENV PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Build Dependencies for Opencv, Dlib and Psycopg2
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    cmake \
    libopencv-dev \
    libdlib-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Installation
RUN pip install opencv-python dlib psycopg2

# MAIN
WORKDIR /code

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY ./fr_as .
```

Here is my Docker Compose:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python /code/fr_as/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - db
    devices:
      - /dev/video0:/dev/video0
    privileged: true
  
  db:
    image: postgres:15
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust"

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Here is my requirements.txt:

```
Django
django-cleanup
django-object-actions
django_user_agents
face-recognition
imutils
pillow
```

I built the container using this command:

```
docker-compose up -d --build
```

And an error appeared when running the code below:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
_, img = cap.read()
```

Here is the error message:

```
OpenCV(4.7.0) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/resize.cpp:4062: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'resize'
```

Looking at the Variable Watch Window, The Values for these variables are:

- _ = False
- img = None

Comment: docker containers don't let you access host devices. not an OpenCV issue. replicate with ffmpeg/guvcview/vlc.

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: Actually, I was just testing with the Dockerfile you have provided and it was working. Could be, because I am not on an intel machine and thus, the python packages were build from scratch instead of using some pre-compiled wheels. Could you try again after changing your `pip` line to `RUN pip install  --no-binary :all: opencv-python dlib psycopg2`

Comment: okey lemme try..

Comment: failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pip install  --no-binary :all: opencv-python dlib psycopg2]: exit code: 1

Comment: got this error message when running that specific line..

Comment: @M.Spiller what operating system are you using?

Comment: @Louis Actually I was using your Dockerfile given above minus the requirements.txt. I am running on an arm64 machine, though, so the container will also be arm64.

Comment: I see.. any suggestions on what I should try next to solve this? @M.Spiller

Comment: The `failed to solve`, you normally get, when a command is waiting for user interaction. What does the docker output before the error look like? Any indication that you should hit enter, or something like that?

Comment: I don’t think so

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251608/discussion-between-louis-and-m-spiller).

Comment: @M.Spiller I have posted new messages in the chat forum. thank you..